# How do I use functions from Project 1 in Project 2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im wondering how I would call functions from Project 1 in Project 2.
What I have already done is adding my first Project as a reference to my second project but if I try to call, for example hello(); it wont work.
I'd really appreciate help.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to collect your common functions in a Project 3 which builds a library.

Comment: It depends on how project 1 and 2 are set up. It one a statically linked library or something?

Comment: You probably did not add the setting for the include path.

Comment: ***it wont work.*** Your question would be much better if you explained what happened when you did this and what type of projects you are using. Currently we are forced to play a game of guess what mistake @provo made with a pretty vague description of the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:
Create a library (Project 3) of the stuff you want to share between projects. Link the library in both projects.

Comment: are you sure that is an answer ? not for me, too short, must be a remark (I do not DV anyway ;-) )